# Python Selenium Webdriver doesn't scroll into div

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I wrote a script to scrape data from SubGraph APIs. It simply click the run button and gets some output code. The problem is that I dhould scroll until the end of the page to get the full output code, unless I get it cutted. This is the way I tried:

```
def find_datasets():
    datasets_url = []

    s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    options = Options()
    options.headless = False
    options.add_argument('window-size=800,600')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

    driver.get("https://v4.subgraph.polygon.oceanprotocol.com/subgraphs/name/oceanprotocol/ocean-subgraph/graphql?query=%7B%0A%20%20pools(orderBy%3A%20createdTimestamp%2C%20orderDirection%3A%20desc)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20datatoken%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20address%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20publishMarketSwapFee%0A%20%20%20%20liquidityProviderSwapFee%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A")
    sleep(15)
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[contains(@class, 'execute-button')]").click()
    sleep(8)
    element = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[contains(@class, 'CodeMirror-lines')]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    
    print(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[contains(@class, 'result-window')]").text)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
```

What am I missing? Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with the class [Actions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) ?

Example:

```
menu = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".nav")
hidden_submenu = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".nav #submenu1")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(menu)
actions.click(hidden_submenu)
actions.perform()
```

Or I think .. you could try to put only

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Comment: I tried to use it instead of driver.execute_script and it returns this error: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".nav"}

Comment: Ok, I navigated to the website and you want the right side element  that it has this xpath "//div[contains(@class, 'CodeMirror-lines')]" the problem there are 3 xpaths with this path. So you need to select one of them "(//div[contains(@class, 'CodeMirror-lines')])[3]".

But the problem it is not that because you need yo go the last element to the right side and it is other xpath is (//div[contains(@class, 'CodeMirror-lines')])[3]//descendant::*[name()="pre"]. 
I would count the elements inside the main element and I would move to it

Comment: links that can help you: 
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium_webdriver/selenium_webdriver_identify_multiple_elements.htm

Answer (score 0):

before do action on the target element, you need invoke scrollIntoView() first.